# Failed to create MenuItemImage with Lambda

Tags: lambda, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to use Lambda to create a MenuItemImage to catch the touch callback:
This works just fine:

```
MenuItemImage* mYouTube = MenuItemImage::create("en_block3.png", "en_block3_hover.png",
        // lambda function handle onClick event
        [=](cocos2d::Ref *pSender) -> bool {
        auto scale = ScaleBy::create(0.5f, 1.1f);
        mYouTube->runAction(scale);
        return true;

    });
```

But when I **define the action `scale` outside of the lambda**, it doesn't works as expect, Visual Studio compile without any problem but the app crashed on menu item clicked:

```
auto scale = ScaleBy::create(0.5f, 1.1f);
MenuItemImage* mYouTube = MenuItemImage::create("en_block3.png", "en_block3_hover.png",
        // lambda function handle onClick event
        [&](cocos2d::Ref *pSender) -> bool {
            mYouTube->runAction(scale);
            return true;
            });
```

Any idea what causes this error? Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `scale` is local variable you have to pass it to the lambda function like this:

```
auto scale = ScaleBy::create(0.5f, 1.1f);
scale->retain();
MenuItemImage* mYouTube = MenuItemImage::create("en_block3.png", "en_block3_hover.png",
        // lambda function handle onClick event
        [&, scale](cocos2d::Ref *pSender) -> bool {
            mYouTube->runAction(scale);
            return true;
            });
```

Also, `ScaleBy` is descending from `Ref` class, so it's a autorelease class. Because you don't use `scale` right away it'll be released from memory (0 reference count) and will cause crash after clicking `mYouTube` button.

That's why you have to call `retain()`. But then you have to remember to call `release()`, when you no longer need it (for example leaving a scene). In my opinion it's better to create this scale animation inside lambda function. Also you can write a simple function, which will create and return `scale` in place.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, my code works and I understand how it work now :)